# How site administration is managed in Django-Angular2 project

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have to use Angular 2+ for front-end and Django as back-end, in my project.

Usually Django provides the '/admin' URL through which we can access the admin portal to do all the site-administration stuffs. But to use Angular 2+ as front-end we need to convert the whole back-end (Django) into [REST](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) API, which is actually recommended.

In this case how can we use the Django Admin URL or its utilities from Angular URLs? Or else whether I have to replicate Django Admin in Angular 2.

It will be a great help if someone can give me some ideas on this.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? The admin is separate from the user front-end of your site. Why can't you leave it as it is?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Thanks for your concern. My thought was .. may be the conversion of back-end Django to Django RF will not allow to access the Django Admin utility anymore, as navigation of URLs will be controlled from Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how the various technologies you are developing in actually coexist.

- Django is the server-side framework.
- DRF (Django REST Framework) is
  used *in addition* to Django, to make it easier to implement a
  RESTful API on top of your Django project. Django REST Framework does
  not *replace* Django. Django REST Framework is an *addition* to
  Django.
- AngularJS is a JavaScript framework that *can* be used in your project (or just parts of your project).

Using Django REST Framework does not suddenly mean that the Django admin interface will 'stop working'.

If your project's URL routing ('`urls.py`') still contains a route connecting the Django admin interface with `/admin` you can still go to `yourproject.com/admin` and it will completely circumvent anything you've done with AngularJS.

Comment: Hi @Kye, many thanks for your reply. I think your idea will help me. I was trying to make sure of all the angles before jumping into the code.. I am new in Angular & Django domain. So from your answer I got to know one thing that even after converting the Django back-end into DRF, we will still be able to access the Django Admin from front-end i.e. Angular using proper routing. Am I right?

Comment: @IndranilPaul Adding AngularJS to your project does not mean that regular Django views do not stop working. Since the Django admin is just a regular Django app, it will stop working. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

It may be late to reply, but Angular and DRF connects over http call.